# Why we can't find inverse function

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I've found that it isn't because it isn't an injection. But i can't find why is that... Can somebody explain this to my step by step?

$$ y= \sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt[5]{\sin x}-2}{\sqrt[5]{\sin x}+2}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, in particular, it is $$y(0)=y(2\pi)=-1.$$  But, since $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin x$ it is $$y(x+2\pi)=y(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.$$ That is, $y$ is periodic with period $2\pi.$ And a periodic function has not inverse.

Comment: Okey, that's it. But speculating, if i hadn't noticed that, and i would create inverse function of this example, am I able to notice it in the end of transformation ?

Comment: The function has inverse on each interval where it is injective. If you try to get the inverse you arrive at $\sin x=\left(\dfrac{2y^3-2}{1-y^3}\right)^5.$ Noting that $\sin x$ is not injective you can get the same conclusion. Why? Because $x=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{2y^3-2}{1-y^3}\right)^5+2k\pi.$

Comment: Okey, i understand. Now, going futher in speculation, if we narrow our domain to $<0;2π>$ this function would have a inverse form, am I correct?

Comment: Note that $h(t)=\dfrac{t-2}{t+2}$ is injective on $[-1,1]$. So $h(\sqrt[3]{\sin x})$ is also injective on $[0,\pi]$ because $\sqrt[3]{\sin x}$ is injective. The same applies to $\sqrt[5]{h(x)}.$ But you have to restric to $[0,\pi]$ because on $[0,\pi+\epsilon]$ the sine is not injective.